# Linux installers fail to detect my root disk (hard disk). Asus Z87-A motherboard

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Windows 7 was succesfully installed on the drive without a hitch. Posting from this OS now.

So far I've tried Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 21.10, the latest Mint and the latest Fedora Core. None of these installers find my hard disk.

I have tried all the settings in the BIOS, and I've tried all the motherboard SATA ports.

The hard disk is not striped.

Comment: My second drive is a 240 GB SSD, which contains an install for my old computer. I wish to save /home from this drive. This drive IS detected. The hard disk is not, regardless if I connect the SSD or not.

Comment: Have you tried alternative SATA ports? Assuming you have more than one.

Comment: In several cases, due to Intel not providing adequate Linux drivers in kernel, SSD can only be detected on Linux when the SATA controller is configured as AHCI, rather than RAID/RST which is often the one configured. Try to change the mode in UEFI settings. Warning: Windows will probably not detect anymore the installation if the controller changes mode, unless a driver is provided manually (see https://superuser.com/questions/531594/windows-how-to-install-driver-from-recovery-command-prompt which describes the reverse).

Comment: I've tried IDE, AHCI and UEFI. In all three cases, Windows 7 boots from the HD and only the SSD is detected by the Linux installer.